# PHP shell_exec taking 30 + seconds to run basic PowerShell script

Tags: php, powershell

I'm trying to write a basic website in PHP to run some PowerShell tasks behind the scenes. My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Maintenance Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php


// Path to the PowerShell script. Remember double backslashes:
$psScriptPath = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SetAHMaintModeON.ps1";

// Execute the PowerShell script, passing the parameters:
$query = shell_exec("powershell -command $psScriptPath");
echo "Maintenance Mode is now enabled!";  



?>

<form method="post" action="home.php">
<input type="submit" name="returnHome" value="Home" <?php 
$_SESSION["siteState"] = "red"; ?>>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the PowerShell code that is getting called:

```
#Import Modules

Import-Module F5 -ErrorAction Stop -Global

#Declare variables

$LtmOne = "myltm.com"
$DataGroupName = "Maintenance_Mode"
$State ="off"

#Connect to F5 LTMs and set Maintenance Mode to on

Connect-F5 $LtmOne
Set-MaintenanceMode -Name $DataGroupName -State $State -Confirm:$false
```

If I run this script outside of PHP, it executes within seconds. However, as soon as I put it behind PHP, the execution shoots up. Is there a code inefficiency that I have? I am by no means an expert PHP developers, so its possible bad code is slowing it down. The only other option I have is to rewrite this all in .NET, which I would prefer not to as I've found PHP to have a much easier learning curve.

Comment: Does it "take 30 seconds to run", or does it timeout after 30 seconds and you don't know if it runs ?

Comment: Yes it does run

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating the site in to IIS instead of Apache and the code executes within seconds. It must be an issue with Apache and PowerShell.